# android self-signed certificate wont work

Tags: android, ssl, certificate, self-signed

Recently I made a self-singed certificate in Apache web server using this tutorial:

http://theheat.dk/blog/?p=1023&cpage=1

Web service require certificate to open. in browser everything goes well. I imported certificates and site will open.

I made BKS file from rootCA.crt, client.crt, winter fell.crt, But no one works.
In Android I get

> SSL3_GET_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE:peer did not return a certificate No CAs
>   known to server for verification?

error message in apache log.

It seems my problem is about combination of certificates to send to server! in browser I use client and rootCA, How can I combine them to send to webserver?

My code:

```
  try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new MyHttpClient(getApplicationContext());
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet("https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/index.php");

        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(get);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return "OK";


    } catch (Exception err) {
        return "Err";
    }
```

And

```
public class MyHttpClient extends DefaultHttpClient {

final Context context;

public MyHttpClient(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected ClientConnectionManager createClientConnectionManager() {
    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    // Register for port 443 our SSLSocketFactory with our keystore
    // to the ConnectionManager
    registry.register(new Scheme("https", newSslSocketFactory(), 443));
    return new SingleClientConnManager(getParams(), registry);
}

private SSLSocketFactory newSslSocketFactory() {
    try {
        // Get an instance of the Bouncy Castle KeyStore format
        KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
        // Get the raw resource, which contains the keystore with
        // your trusted certificates (root and any intermediate certs)
        InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.comb);
        try {
            // Initialize the keystore with the provided trusted certificates
            // Also provide the password of the keystore
            trusted.load(in, "mysecret".toCharArray());
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }

        // Pass the keystore to the SSLSocketFactory. The factory is responsible
        // for the verification of the server certificate.
        SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(trusted);
        // Hostname verification from certificate
        // http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d4e506
        //sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

        return sf;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
}
```

Your helps really appreciated!

Comment: What version of Android were you experiencing this problem on?

Answer (score 1):

Use below given custom `SSLSocketFactory` class.

```
public class AndroidSSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(
            "X509");
    public AndroidSSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        super(truststore);
        tmf.init(truststore);
        TrustManager[] trustManagers = tmf.getTrustManagers();
        final X509TrustManager origTrustmanager = (X509TrustManager)trustManagers[0];
        TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return origTrustmanager.getAcceptedIssuers();
            }

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(
                    java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                    throws CertificateException {
                origTrustmanager.checkClientTrusted(chain, authType);
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(
                    java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                    throws CertificateException {
                origTrustmanager.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
            }
        };
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{tm}, null);
    }
}
```

This class manages the Transport layer security between server and Android through X509 certificate.

Use it in your `newSslSocketFactory()` method. Replace

`SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(trusted);`

With

```
SSLSocketFactory sf = new AndroidSSLSocketFactory(trusted);
```

Hope this will help you.

> **Info :-** `HttpClient` is deprecated from Android 6.0, you should use `HttpURLConnection` instead.[Link](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client).

**Update 1:-**
As per [this](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#SelfSigned) link in order to work with self-signed certificate You can create your own `TrustManager`. So make changes in TrustManager code. This might help future users.

Comment: Nope. wont changed any thing

Comment: @Igor Ganapolsky Thanks for drawing my attention on that, I just return null from getAcceptedIssuers() as it will make TrustManager to Trust all certificates. As it didnt works for Mehdi I will update my answer soon.